# compile tkinter to executable using py2exe, having issue with xlrd

Tags: python, tkinter, py2exe, xlrd

I made a GUI using tkinter. My GUI is linked to an Excel file so I used the xlrd package. After compiling the GUI to executable using py2exe, when I try to open the executable file I get a text file with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "xlrd\__init__.pyc", line 4, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\dist\\library.zip\\xlrd\\version.txt'
```

I have no idea what that "version.txt" file is or why it doesn't exist in the directory. I have tried to compile an executable GUI that doesn't need the xlrd package and everything worked fine. This is my setup.py file script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=['main.py'],options={'py2exe':{'includes':['xlrd']}})
```

I'm fairly new to python and making executable applications. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The version of `xlrd` that you are using is out of date; `version.txt` has been eradicated.

Try the first one of the following versions that meets your requirements:

[0.9.0](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/archive/master.zip) -- XLS and XLSX files, Python 2.6. 2.7, 3.2+
[0.8.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.8.0) -- XLS and XLSX files, Python 2.3 to 2.7
[0.7.9](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.7.9) -- XLS files only, Python 2.1 to 2.7

Note: The released 0.9.0 is not production quality; several bugs have been fixed in the master branch so get a ZIP file from github using the link above, not the tar.gz from PyPI.

Comment: Thank you John, I eventually decided to dump the xlrd idea and created data structures to store the data in the Excel files, then I just work off the pickled files. Thanks for the answer.